# How do I setup a localhost using the Sites folder on my Mac?

Tags: macos

How do I setup a localhost using the "Sites" folder on my Mac?

Comment: For clarification, this is enabling `http://localhost/~USERNAME/` to serve your own `~/Sites/` folder.

Answer (score 11):

The web sharing checkbox was removed in 10.8, but `sudo apachectl start` also enbales the launchd agent permanently (see `cat /usr/sbin/apachectl`). To make `http://localhost/~username/` work, you can save something like this as `/etc/apache2/users/username.conf`:

```
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

If you want to direct localhost to `~/Sites/`, you can change DocumentRoot in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.

You can add a virtual host by uncommenting `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, adding `127.0.0.1 testsite.dev` to `/etc/hosts`, and adding this to `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/testsite/"
    ServerName testsite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

`sudo apachectl restart` applies changes.

Comment: I wonder, is it possible to change location for this folder `/Users/username/Sites/` to new one? for example `/Users/username/PHP/`

Comment: I needed to also uncomment two lines in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`: `LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so` and `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`.

Comment: I also needed to uncomment a line in `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`: `Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf`, otherwise the per-user `/etc/apache2/users/*.conf` files are not read.  -- Hat tip https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/forbidden-403-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-username-on-this-server/#comment-2832810306

Answer (score 6):

Open *System Preferences » Sharing*, and enable *Web Sharing*.

On Mountain Lion *Web Sharing* has been removed from preferences, so use `sudo apachectl start` to start Apache.

You'll find the URLs specified there. For example, my *Sites* folder `/Users/danielbeck/Sites` is accessible as `http://10.0.1.2/~danielbeck/`.

Comment: Thank you, but I wanted to get local php working such as WordPress. I have seen many posts, but none about the "Sites" folder.

Comment: @david In that case, your question is lacking your actual requirements. You need to configure Apache to support PHP, just as on any other system. `httpd.conf` is in `/etc/apache2`, and while it's been a while since I worked with it, you might have success by uncommenting the line containing `php5_module`, and toggling Web Sharing to restart Apache.